# Does ajax-bootstrap-select support liveSearch?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have a basic dropdown that uses bootstrap-selectpicker library to search the dropdown options using a contains format and I populated dropdown options using ajax-bootstrap-select plugin https://github.com/truckingsim/Ajax-Bootstrap-Select 
and I am trying to find a way to search the ajax populated dropdown options using the "contains" operations as in original selectpicker.

I was previously using selectpicker only and just used ajax plugin recently and I am not sure if the plugin's function is only to fetches the options from the 'url'. 
or if it does the search from populated options and I've missed any parameter while coding for it.

```html
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-selected-text-format="count" data-actions-box="true" data-live-search="true" data-show-tick="false" data-live-search-style="contains">
</select>
```

```
<script>
var options = {

    ajax: {

    url: '/Search/Typeahead',

    type: 'POST',

    dataType: 'json',

    data: function () {
        var params = {
            q: '{{{q}}}'
        };

        return params;
    }
},

locale: {
        emptyTitle: 'Select and Begin Typing'
},

preprocessData: function (data) {
    var i, l = data.length, array = [];
    if (l) {
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            var curr = data[i];

            array.push({
                'value': curr.value,
                'text': curr.text,
                'disabled': curr.disabled,
                'selected': curr.selected,
            });
        }
    }
    return array;
},

preserveSelected: false
};
$('select.selectpicker').selectpicker({liveSearch: true }).ajaxSelectPicker(options);

$('.bootstrap-select').selectpicker();

//The dropdown options are not displayed at all if I use **.filter('.with-ajax')** as below:
//$('select.selectpicker').selectpicker({liveSearch: true }).filter('.with-ajax').ajaxSelectPicker(options);

//Also tried using <select class="selectpicker **with-ajax** " but it doesn't work for me either

$('select.selectpicker').trigger('change');
</script>
```

I have the ajax populated options but the searching for a keyword does not alter the dropdown options.

Comment: That is just an extension for bootstrap-select ( https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select ) and it requires bootstrap-select to be initialized first to work. Are you initializing bootstrap-select first?

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply, Steve. Yes I have initialised the bootstrap-select before ajax-selectpicker plugin.

Comment: e.g. If I remove **.ajaxSelectPicker(options)** from **Javascript**

and add  **asp-for="DDOptions" asp-items="Model.DDOptions"** 
in **<select>**

then it works as expected using bootstrap-select- i.e. searches using "contains"

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.bootstrap-select').selectpicker('refresh');
```

instead of

```
$('.bootstrap-select').selectpicker();
```

Sometimes you can see the change in HTML using the inspector, and need to refresh the `selectpicker` after a change.